# Meteor / Javascript - How to return 2 or more functions from a method on the server at the same time?

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods, return

I'm quite new to this but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {

    return Meteor.methods({

      removeAllNewOrgs: function() {
        return newOrgPhoneNumbers.remove({});
        return newOrgansations.remove({});
      }

    });

  });
}
```

It fails on the second return and I am aware that once a return is completed the method exits.  How can I add multiple commands/returns into a method like I'm trying to?  I can't find what I'm after out there.

Thanks so much,

Rob

Comment: Why not return an array?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have to be honest, this turned out to be a duplicate post.  I've been working on it and other things for a few days and posted earlier and hadn't realised (in my blurred brain state).  I've just now supplied the answer that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was supplied in another thread.  Sorry for cross threading, it was my mistake (overly tired).

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    return Meteor.methods({

      //Use this to emplty the form data
      removeAllNewOrgs: function() {

        var PhoneNumbers = newOrgPhoneNumbers.remove({});  
        var Organsations = newOrgansations.remove({});  

        return {
          PhoneNumbers : PhoneNumbers,
          Organsations : Organsations
        }

      }

    });

  });
}
```

It works beautifully.